# How do I handle errors or perform promise chaining using redis pipeline in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, error-handling, redis, pipeline, ioredis

I am using the `ioredis` library to perform a series of commands within a redis pipeline.

Here is a simplified example of what I am trying to do:

```
// Assume ioredis var is a successfully-connected ioredis client
const pipeline = ioredis.pipeline();

pipeline.hset('mykey', { foo: 'bar' })
.then(() => {
    pipeline.expire('mykey', 1000, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error: ', JSON.stringify(err));
        } else console.info('Success!');
    });
});

pipeline.exec();
```

You'll notice this example has both a promise-chain and some error handling for the second promise.  When I perform this logic directly against the ioredis client (no pipeline), it works just fine, but when I use the pipeline, an error of an empty object is thrown.

Documentation on ioredis is not very helpful, so any information that can point me in the right direction is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation, pipeline is used when you have multiple commands and want them to execute in the given order. You can get the results in one shot or can use cb style for getting results. As you are using both, you can also use `exec` on the pipeline chain directly.

```
// Assume ioredis var is a successfully-connected ioredis client
const pipeline = ioredis.pipeline();

pipeline
.hset('mykey', { foo: 'bar' })
.then((err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error: ', JSON.stringify(err));
        } else console.info('Success!');
})
.expire('mykey', 1000) 
.then((err, results) => {
    // do things here
})
.exec((err, results) => {
    // `err` will null always
    // result === [[null, 'OK'], [null, 'bar']...]
    // result ==== [[err,result],...] from every command you run
});
```

I would recommend you to re-check the documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis) (check pipelining section). It is not verbose, but once you go through it and check out the examples it will work.

Comment: Is there a way to change the return value of the result of a pipeline command?